# Unexpected hospitalization in the EU without EHIC, am I covered?

Tags: europe, health, insurance

I recently went to France. While there I suffered pain/discomfort and was hospitalized. I was given full checkout - Xray, blood test, blood pressure test and a chat with a doctor. No complaints at all. I was given notes to give to my doctor. Later I received a letter from the hospital asking for a back copy of my European Health Insurance Card.

Before I left for France I took out travel insurance with the airline I was traveling with, plus with my bank. So as far as I understand it I have two lots of insurance. Neither mentioned anything about a European Health Insurance Card.

I am now faced with the possibility of a big bill with little means to pay it, all because I didn't know about the European Health Insurance Card.

What can I do now? Is there some way to get at least partially reimbursed by my health insurance (e.g. the NHS)?

Comment: Hi Nick and welcome to Travel.SE. What is your question actually?!

Comment: What's your question? Did you try to contact your health insurer or your travel insurer about the matter?

Comment: Where do you live? Did you tell the hospital where you live when you were there? Did you show them any of your paperwork related to travel insurance?

Comment: [Wikipedia has all the basics on EHIC cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card) - you might be confused by having dropped the I (=Insurance) from the acronym

Comment: I (aggressively) edited the question, hoping to make it “re-openable”. The basics of the EHIC, the difference with travel insurance, etc. are covered elsewhere but what about the OP situations? Official websites suggest he could have faxed/emailed for a “Provisional Replacement Certificate” at the time he was admitted to the hospital but it's also too late for that now. Since the EHIC is free, it seems that it's not really a separate insurance but merely a way to establish that you are in fact already covered by your home country health care system…

Comment: … Is that to say that it would still be possible to be (partly?) reimbursed after going through some red tape? Or is everything lost? Does anybody have any first-hand experience with this problem? Could it be as simple as applying for a card now and sending its number to the hospital or is that likely to create even more problems?

Comment: @Annoyed Without more info from the OP, I'm not sure your edits are quite correct. We know they had some sort of travel insurance with a health component, but we don't know if they live in an EU country and hence if they are covered by an EU national health system. Also, note that NHS = National Health Service, not which isn't much like a US style Health Insurance scheme as it's universal and free at the point of use

Comment: @Gagravarr The OP can let us know if this reflects his or her situation, I am just trying to make an interesting question out of a lost one (already closed, OP apparently not coming back…). I am assuming the OP comes from the EU because it wouldn't make sense to ask someone else for an EHIC but in fact, the original post had no question at all and did not mention explicitly the EHIC.

Comment: I think we'd be much better off leaving this one closed, and someone starting a new one eg "What is an EHIC, and why should an EU Citizen get one before travelling within Europe?" or something like that

Comment: Also, I don't know the NHS very well but I do know the basics (and would have no particular reason to be familiar with US health insurance). My understanding is that beside directly providing are, as far as European regulations are concerned, the NHS also more or less fits the role devoted to private or state health insurance systems in other EU countries (in particular, it should issue EHIC and cover treatment costs when EU rules mandate it).

Comment: @Gagravarr We have plenty of “What is the EHIC?” questions and it's easy to find tons of info about that on the web. The point of the question is that in this scenario it's now too late to get an EHIC or even a PRC. In this situation, it's useless to be told “You should have got one before travelling”.

Comment: @NickMorse What nationality are you ? I'm assuming you are British

Answer (score 4):

The European Health Insurance Card (EHIC) formerly known as the E111, can be used to cover any necessary medical treatment due to either an accident or illness within the European Economic Area (EEA). The EHIC entitles the holder to state-provided medical treatment within the country they are visiting and the service provided will be the same as received by a person covered by the country’s ‘insured’ medical scheme.

All British citizens (it is only applicable to British citizens I believe, although I'm sure similar cards exists for other european citizens) are encouraged to carry the EHIC when travelling in the EEA, in additional to travel insurance. (It usually has to be renewed every few years).

Edit:

In addition whilst it is not compulsory to have, I have heard many stories of Brits travelling to places like Spain on holiday, even though they had travel insurance, because they weren't carrying EHIC they encountered many problems with medical assistance/hospitalization etc.

**For British citizens travelling within the EU, the only EU country where you do not need an EHIC card on you at the time of medical assistance and/or hospitalisation is when travelling to Malta. This is because a reciprocal agreement exists between the two countries for the medical treatment of it citizens.**

**For all other EU countries including Norway, Switzerland and Liechtenstein (if you are British at least) not having a valid EHIC card (even if you have travel insurance) on you at the time of such medical assistance could lead to very BIG problems.**

**It is also VERY important to note: You certainly CANNOT apply for a EHIC card (wrt being British) and expect to use it after a medical event has occurred in EU countries including Norway, Switzerland and Liechtenstein.**

More info about EHIC can be found here:

- [NHS Choices - EHIC](http://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/Healthcareabroad/EHIC/Pages/about-the-ehic.aspx) (Some UK Specific bits, but ltos of info)
- [EU Commission - EHIC](http://ehic.europa.eu/) (EU Wide)

Comment: I think all citizens of the concerned countries are pushed to get this card when travelling across Europe.

Comment: @Vince In the UK it is widely known by most people, but still perhaps more so commonly referred by its former name of "E111".

Comment: @everyone The other thing which could even happen I suppose is:  "What happens if you have a valid in date EHIC card and leave it at home?" I think you have to have it on you at the time of incident OTHERWISE too many complications/problems will arise !

Answer (score 4):

From the [EHIC information site](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=1021&langId=en&intPageId=1737) concerning France:

> **Reimbursement**
>
> - Reimbursements are claimed in France from the local CPAM office (Caisse Primaire D'Assurance Maladie).
> - You will need to provide the treatment form ("feuille de soins"), copies of receipts and prescriptions, a copy of your European Health Insurance Card, your address of residence and your bank details, including International Bank Account Number (IBAN) and Bank Identifier Code (BIC). Confirmation of your refund will be sent to your home address.
> - You can claim back around 70% of the standard treatment cost.
> - If you were unable to submit a claim during your stay in France, contact your national health insurance provider when you return home.

It is not immediately clear whether not having the card issued before the event is going to affect your chances of reimbursement. It stands to reason it should not, as it is simply a document certifying your health insurance status back home, not a separate medical insurance. At any rate, you are advised to contact your national health insurance provider as soon as possible to receive more guidance how to obtain reimbursement. It's not very clear, but from the wording, you will be required to pay the full amount and only after that seek reimbursement.

See also:

- [More on EHIC](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=559&langId=en)
- [EHIC FAQ](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=857&langId=en&intPageId=1304)